# Different result with same if / else condition

Tags: java, if-statement

I always thought that this:

```
Object o1 = true ? new Integer(1) : new Double(2.0);
```

is the same as doing this:

```
Object o2;
if (true)
    o2 = new Integer(1);
else
    o2 = new Double(2.0);
```

But as output I got `1.0` for the first example and `1` for the second one.

Why they give me different results? And why I've got a `Double` result in the first place?